# matplotlib fill function plotting versus time cuts through graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, fill

I have a strange issue where my plot is being bisected by an errant line, and the fill is subsequently executed improperly.

```
plt.fill(temp.index, temp['meas'].values)
```

[image].

I'm using pandas to manipulate my data, so when looking at the temp dataframe it's set up like so:

```
In: temp.index
Out: Index([00:00:00, 00:01:00, 00:02:00, ...], dtype='object')

In: temp['meas'].values
Out: array([0, 0, 0, ..., Decimal('3.040'), Decimal('3.040'), Decimal('3.040')], dtype=object)
```

When I try just a regular plot, matplotlib functions as expected.

```
plt.plt(temp.index, temp['meas'].values)
```

[image].

The arrays are of the same length, and the last value in the index is a time object of 23:59, not 00:00, so I'm not sure why it's cutting back to the origin at the end of the plot.

My matplotlib version is 1.4.0, and pandas is 0.15.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fill_between()` like so:

```
plt.fill(temp.index, 0, temp['meas'].values)
```

That should fill everything between 0 and your 'Y' values.